# Count non-blank text cells in a column

Tags: excel

Data looks like:

```
A      B
Joe    1
Mary   2.5
Sam    1.2
       0
Frank  1.3
Bob    2.1
       2.2
Tim    0.6
```

The result should be 6 because six cells in the column have a name, and two are empty.

Disregarding any associated value in ColumnB, how do I count all cells in ColumnA that have no value (are empty)?

Comment: I am not sure I understand... Can you give me an example?

Comment: Thought I did: for the above example, the value would be 6 because 6 cells in the column have a name, and 2 are empty. Summing 1 for each non-empty cell in a column.

Comment: `=counta(A:A)` Put that in C1

Comment: Is that what you wanted?

Comment: It actually looks like COUNTIF(A:A, "<>") works.

Comment: You can use COUNTIF but simpler is `COUNTA`. Check the excel's help :)

Comment: Oh, sorry, yes I misread your comment as a call to COUNT and not COUNTA: the latter is indeed a simpler solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of an answer:

```
=COUNTA(A:A)
```

as mentioned in a comment by @Siddharth Rout.